# Getting Higest Value in Sqlite and Set Text to TextView

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

Can anybody tell me how to get highest number in SQLITE and set it to TextView?

```
public Cursor MaxPrice() {

    Cursor m = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT MAX( " + Pro_Price + " ) FROM "+ TABLE_NAME + " " , null);
    return m;

}
```

Here is the other part in other class:

```
    Database dbb = new Database(this);
    dbb.open();
    String Hexpense = dbb.MaxPrice();
    tvHighestExpense.setText( Hexpense);
```

Comment: Do not use rawQuery - use query instead ("max(column)" is also possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method MaxPrice() returns a Cursor. So you should extract the value from the first (and unique) row that the Cursor contains:

```
Cursor c = dbb.MaxPrice()
c.moveToFirst();
if (!c.isAfterLast()) {
   tvHighestExpense.setText(c.getLong(0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor m=...
long max=m.getLong(0/*column index*/);
tvHighestExpense.setText(String.valueOf(max));
```